# Auto-complete in Visual Studio for Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, autocomplete

I'm coding C# in Visual Studio for my Unity project.

When I add a new script file to my project, I can  open it in VS.

However, VS doesn't make any auto-complete specificly for unity, as I saw in a unity tutorial.

How can I get this VS auto-complete?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you have Visual Studio Unity3d tools. You can download them for free [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SebastienLebreton.VisualStudio2015ToolsforUnity) Also your class also must inherit `MonoBehaviour` class in order to show you these auto-complete features. Enjoy coding :)